# Asymptotic approximate solution of the parabolic cylinder differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, approximation-theory

In chapter 3 (example 4) of the book "Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers", by Bender and Orszag, I want to get the approximate solution for $+\inf$ for the parabolic cylinder differential equation:

$y'' + (\nu + 1/2 -x^2/4)y = 0$.

First I get rid of the singularity at infinite using the following transformation:

$y = e^{S(x)}$
yielding

$S'' + S'^2 + \nu + 1/2 - x^2/4=0$.

Then I assume the following approximations:

$S'' << S'^2$ and $\nu + 1/2 <<1/4 x^2$
which gives

$S(x) \approx \pm x^2/4$ when $x \to \inf$.

This is the controlling factor of the general differential equation. To get the leading behavior I assume that

$S(x) \approx \pm x^2/4 + C(x)$
where
$C(x) << \pm x^2/4 $.

I know that the answer to this problem is given by

$y \approx C_1 x^{-(\nu+1)} e^{x^2/4 }$
and
$y \approx C_2 x^{\nu} e^{-x^2/4 }$.

However I don't know how to reach such result. The differential equation for $C(x)$ is given as
$(\pm 1/2 + C'') + (\pm x/2 + C')^2 + \nu + 1/2 - x^2/4 = 0$,

Using the approximation for $C(x)$ I get that

$C' << \pm x/2$ and $C'' << \pm 1/2$,
hence, the differential equation would not depend on $C(x)$, which makes no sense.

I have tried to assume only one of these conditions at a time, however, even so, I do not get to the desired result.

Comment: It has been answered in the physics exchange, [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/520086/asymptotic-approximate-solution-of-the-parabolic-cylinder-differential-equation).

Answer (score 0):

*I do not know how much this could help you.*

If we make
$$y=e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}\, z$$ the equation becomes
$$z''-x z'+\nu  z=0$$ the solution of which being (try [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+z%27%27-x+z%27%2Ba+z%3D0+for+z))
$$z=c_1 H_{\nu }\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+c_2 \, _1F_1\left(-\frac{\nu
   }{2};\frac{1}{2};\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$$ where appear Hermite polynomials and Kummer confluent hypergeometric function.

For large values of the argument, the expansions are
$$H_{\nu }\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=x^{\nu } \left(i^{\nu } 2^{\nu /2} \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi  \nu }{2}\right)-i
   \sqrt{2} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  \nu
   }{2}\right)\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)$$
$$_1F_1\left(-\frac{\nu
   }{2};\frac{1}{2};\frac{x^2}{2}\right)=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} x^{-\nu } \left(\frac{2^{\frac{\nu +1}{2}} \sqrt{\pi }}{\Gamma
   \left(-\frac{\nu }{2}\right)
   x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)+x^{\nu } \left(\frac{i^{\nu }
   2^{-\frac\nu 2} \sqrt{\pi }}{\Gamma \left(\frac{\nu
   +1}{2}\right)}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Basically, my question is how to get to these approximations.

Comment: @EdisonSantos. Have a look at DLMF. You will find a bunch of approximations.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of DLMF, and these relations do help me. However I need to learn to deduce them.